# How to preserve the organization in directories (or groups) of the source files, with cocoapods?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

Is there a way, in the `.podspec` to specify that the source files should stay organized after being imported?

So far, I have tried this

```
s.source_files  = 'Classes/**/*.{h,m}'
s.preserve_paths = 'Classes/**/*.{h,m}'
```

but it does not work. The document of `cocoapods` is not very clear on this option.

Comment: Yes, I would like the same. I have a local pod I'm working on and I'd love some folder organization of the source files under "Development Pods".

Comment: Cool, there's a pull request already, hope it will be there soon. https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/2647

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've found to have subfolders is via sub-specs. While that doesn't mirror the file system layout, you can at least arrange your sources into groups. The example below will leave you with two folders, "Core" and "Cells".

```
s.subspec 'Core' do |core|
   core.source_files = 'Classes/ios/*.{m,h}'
end

s.subspec 'Cells' do |cells|
    cells.source_files = 'Classes/ios/Cells/*.{m,h}'
    cells.dependency 'iOSShared/Core'
end
```

Comment: I have noticed that if have x subspecs, then the argument 'bla bla' of   s.prefix_header_contents = 'bla bla' will be copied x times in `Pods-MyPod-prefix.pch`. A hack is to add `cells.prefix_header_contents = ''` and `core.prefix_header_contents = '`. Hope this can help, in case of.